# Getting "NoneType object has no attribute" when using "with ... as" for custom context manager

Tags: python, contextmanager

I wrote a simple context manager in Python for handling unit tests (and to try to learn context managers):

```
class TestContext(object):
    test_count=1
    def __init__(self):
        self.test_number = TestContext.test_count
        TestContext.test_count += 1

    def __enter__(self):
        pass

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback):
        if exc_value == None:
            print 'Test %d passed' %self.test_number
        else:
            print 'Test %d failed: %s' %(self.test_number, exc_value)
        return True
```

If I write a test as follows, everything works okay.

```
test = TestContext()
with test:
   print 'running test %d....' %test.test_number
   raise Exception('this test failed')
```

However, if I try to use with...as, I don't get a reference to the TestContext() object.  Running this:

```
with TestContext() as t:
    print t.test_number
```

Raises the exception `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'test_number'`.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Assuming that you need to access the context manager created in the `with` statement, [`__enter__` needs to return `self`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__enter__). If you don't need to access it, `__enter__` can return whatever you would like.

> The with statement will bind this method’s return value to the target(s) specified in the as clause of the statement, if any.

This will work.

```
class TestContext(object):
    test_count=1
    def __init__(self):
        self.test_number = TestContext.test_count
        TestContext.test_count += 1

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback):
        if exc_value == None:
            print 'Test %d passed' % self.test_number
        else:
            print 'Test %d failed: %s' % (self.test_number, exc_value)
        return True
```

Comment: Note that there is no *requirement* for a context manager to return `self`. It is a very handy default, so that you can create the context manager in the `with` statement, but a context manager is free to return whatever it likes from `__enter__`. For the specific usecase of the OP, where the `TestContext()` is created in the `with` statement, returning `self `is indeed the way to go.

Comment: @MartijnPieters You are completely correct. I added a disclaimer about that.

Answer (score 14):

```
def __enter__(self):
    return self
```

will make it work. The value returned from this method will be assigned to the `as` variable.

See also [the Python doc](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#grammar-token-with_stmt):

> If a target was included in the `with` statement, the return value from `__enter__()` is assigned to it.

If you only need the number, you can even change the context manager's logic to

```
class TestContext(object):
    test_count=1
    def __init__(self):
        self.test_number = TestContext.test_count
        TestContext.test_count += 1

    def __enter__(self):
        return self.test_number

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback):
        if exc_value == None:
            print 'Test %d passed' % self.test_number
        else:
            print 'Test %d failed: %s' % (self.test_number, exc_value)
        return True
```

and then do

```
with TestContext() as test_number:
    print test_number
```

Answer (score 6):

According to [PEP 343,](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) the `with EXPR as VAR` statement **doesn't** assign to `VAR` the result of `EXPR`, but rather the result of `EXPR.__enter__()`. The first example worked because you referenced the `test` variable itself.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the code here is python 2 rather than 3, and didn't work when I ran. From https://realpython.com/python-with-statement/#writing-a-sample-class-based-context-manager the following example worked for me:

```py
>>> class HelloContextManager:
...     def __enter__(self):
...         print("Entering the context...")
...         return "Hello, World!"
...     def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb):
...         print("Leaving the context...")
...         print(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb, sep="\n")
...

>>> with HelloContextManager() as hello:
...     print(hello)
...
Entering the context...
Hello, World!
Leaving the context...
None
None
None
```