# Python open() Function Context Manager

Tags: python

How do I found the built in open() **enter** and **exit** magic methods? When go to the built in function, all I see is docstrings with a pass at the end. I'm digging into the topic of Context Managers and would like to view them for that particular function. Am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: Do you mean the with statement since you said context manager? Try this: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-build-custom-context-managers-in-python-31727ffe96e1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python with...as for custom context manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34749943/python-with-as-for-custom-context-manager)